# Only GPU build solution from Chromium

Tags: build, webrtc, gpu, chromium, ninja

I just wanted to know is it possible to build specifically GPU from the chromium using ninja(gn).

For example: In the GN documentation I saw something like,

> --filters=
>         Semicolon-separated list of label patterns used to limit the set of
>         generated projects (see "gn help label_pattern"). Only matching targets
>         and their dependencies will be included in the solution. Only used for
>         Visual Studio, Xcode and JSON.

Can anyone who used this help me out!

**PS**: Visual Studio(.sln) with only GPU project in the solution is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you referring to building a VS solution for the contents of GPU folder only: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/gpu/?

Comment: yes... Asesh a solution which has only GPU and its dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--filters` argument to `gn` to restrict generating VS project files for only the projects you would like to build. In your case, you can use the following command:

```
gn gen --ide=vs --filters=//gpu --no-deps out\YourBuildFolder
```

Comment: Just a small doubt what's the difference between --filters=//gpu and --filters=//media/gpu can u expalin

Comment: @vishal Looks like `//gpu` includes tests for ANGLE: https://github.com/google/angle and `//media/gpu` includes code for encoder and decoder

Comment: okay,then the media/gpu along with its dependencies, can be built using the ```gn gen --ide=vs --filters=//media/gpu  out\YourBuildFolder``` ?

Comment: well I was able to build media/gpu along with its dependencies with the following ```gn gen out/debug --sln=chrome --filters=//media/gpu/* --ide=vs2019 --no-deps --args="is_component_build = true is_debug = true is_clang=true enable_nacl=false"```  Thanks.